# BlackBerry Menu Item

Tags: blackberry

What is the correct way in order to push an screen when the user press a Menu Item? I'm developing my code in this way but i don't know if it is the right:

```
    private MenuItem _descriptionItem = new MenuItem("Descripción",110, 10) {
    public void run() {
        int selectedIndex = _listField.getSelectedIndex();
        final Event event = (Event)_listElements.elementAt(selectedIndex);
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Dialog.inform(event.getDescription());
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

menu items are executed on the event thread. So you can remove invokeLater code.

```
 private MenuItem _descriptionItem = new MenuItem("Descripción",110, 10) {
    public void run() {
        int selectedIndex = _listField.getSelectedIndex();
        final Event event = (Event)_listElements.elementAt(selectedIndex);
        Dialog.inform(event.getDescription());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

private MenuItem MNU_BACK = new MenuItem(null, 100000000, 100) {
               public void run() {
                    closeform();
           }

```
         public String toString() {
                 return "BACK";
     }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually deprecated:

```
private MenuItem _descriptionItem = new MenuItem("Descripción",110, 10) 
{
    public void run() {
        int selectedIndex = _listField.getSelectedIndex();
        final Event event = (Event)_listElements.elementAt(selectedIndex);
        Dialog.inform(event.getDescription());
    }
};
```

Use this instead:

```
private MenuItem _descriptionItem = new MenuItem(new StringProvider("Descripción"),110, 10)
{
    public void run() {
        int selectedIndex = _listField.getSelectedIndex();
        final Event event = (Event)_listElements.elementAt(selectedIndex);
        Dialog.inform(event.getDescription());
    }
};
```

This will avoid compiler warnings when using Menu Item.